# Inserting date from string: CAST vs CONVERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, type-conversion, cast

Consider the following two ways to convert a datetime varchar string into a date field:

```
SELECT convert(date, '2012-12-21 21:12:00', 20) -- Only date is needed
SELECT cast('2012-12-21 21:12:00' as date) -- Only date is needed
```

Both return what I expect: The date excluding the time, in as a date datatype.

My question is: Is there any pro and cons of doing either way?

Comment: This question can be expanded to "what is the difference between cast and convert?", and is actually well answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The (formerly) accepted answer <del>is</del>was incorrect as it <del>is</del>was a bad and misleading test. The two queries being compared do not do the same thing due to a simple typo that causes them to not be an apples-to-apples comparison. The test in the accepted answer is unfairly biased in favor of the `CAST` operation. The issue is that the `CONVERT` operation is being done with `convert(date, GETDATE()+num,20)` -- a value to convert that changes per row -- while the `CAST` operation is being done with a simple `cast(GETDATE() as date)` -- a value to convert that is consistent across all rows and is replaced in the execution plan as a constant. And in fact, looking at the XML execution plan even shows the actual operation performed as being `CONVERT(date,getdate(),0)` !!

Insofar as my testing shows (after making them equal via using `cast(GETDATE()+num as date)`), the times varry with them being mostly the same (which makes sense if they are both reduced to being `CONVERT` anyway) or the `CONVERT` winning:

```sql
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
    ;with t as (
               select convert(date, GETDATE(),20) as fecha , 0 as num
             union all
             select convert(date, GETDATE()+num,20) as fecha, num+1 from t where num<1000000)
    select max(fecha)
      from t
    option (maxrecursion  0);
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF;

-- 4754-07-23
--Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 6000008, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0

-- SQL Server Execution Times:
--   CPU time = 9031 ms,  elapsed time = 9377 ms.



-- VS    

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
    ;with t as (
               select cast(GETDATE() as date) as fecha , 0 as num
             union all
             select cast(GETDATE() as date) as fecha, num+1 from t where num<1000000)
    select max(fecha)
      from t
    option (maxrecursion  0);
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF;

--2016-08-26
--Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 6000008, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0

-- SQL Server Execution Times:
--   CPU time = 8969 ms,  elapsed time = 9302 ms.




SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
    ;with t as (
               select cast(GETDATE() as date) as fecha , 0 as num
             union all
             select cast(GETDATE()+num as date) as fecha, num+1 from t where num<1000000)
    select max(fecha)
      from t
    option (maxrecursion  0);
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF;

-- 4754-07-23
--Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 6000008, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0

-- SQL Server Execution Times:
--   CPU time = 9438 ms,  elapsed time = 9878 ms.
```

The main difference between [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is that `CONVERT` allows for the "style" to be specified. The "style" not only allows for tailoring the *output* when converting a non-string to a string, but also allows for specifying the *input* format when converting a string to a non-string:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '5/10/2016', 101); -- 101 = mm/dd/yyyy
-- 2016-05-10


SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '5/10/2016', 103); -- 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
-- 2016-10-05
```

Now compare that *functionally* with `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST('13/5/2016' AS DATE);
-- Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 71
-- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.


SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '13/5/2016', 101); -- 101 = mm/dd/yyyy
-- Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 76
-- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.


SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '13/5/2016', 103); -- 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
-- 2016-05-13
```

---

One additional thing to mention about `CAST`: because it does not have the "style" parameter, the format of the date string passed in is assumed to be that of the current culture (a session property). The current culture is denoted by the `@@LANGID` and `@@LANGUAGE` system variables. This means that the `CAST` statement that failed in the test directly above could succeed for a different culture / language. The following tests shows this behavior and how that same date string does work with `CAST` when the current language is "French" (and would work with several others, based on the values in the `dateformat` column in `sys.syslanguages`):

```sql
IF (@@LANGID <> 0) -- us_english
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Changing LANGUAGE to English...';
    SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
    SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS [CurrentLanguage], @@LANGID AS [LangID];
END;

SELECT @@LANGUAGE, CAST('13/5/2016' AS DATE) AS [Test 1];
-- Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 71
-- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
GO

SELECT @@LANGUAGE, CONVERT(DATE, '13/5/2016', 103) AS [Test 2]; -- 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
-- us_english   2016-05-13
GO


IF (@@LANGID <> 2) -- Français
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Changing LANGUAGE to French...';
    SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
    SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS [CurrentLanguage], @@LANGID AS [LangID];
END;

SELECT @@LANGUAGE, CAST('13/5/2016' AS DATE) AS [Test 3];
-- 2016-05-13
GO

SELECT @@LANGUAGE, CONVERT(DATE, '13/5/2016', 103) AS [Test 4]; -- 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
-- Français 2016-05-13
GO


-- Reset current language, if necessary.
IF (@@LANGID <> @@DEFAULT_LANGID)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Language sysname;

    SELECT @Language = sl.[alias]
    FROM   sys.syslanguages sl
    WHERE  sl.[langid] = @@DEFAULT_LANGID;

    PRINT N'Changing LANGUAGE back to default: ' + @Language + N'...';

    SET LANGUAGE @Language;
    SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS [CurrentLanguage], @@LANGID AS [LangID];
END;
```

Comment: Long overdue, but thanks so much for your time providing this thorough answer. I just revisited this today to write a store procedure and your answer helped a lot! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any 'performance' differences between the two.  Apparently "CONVERT" is Sql Server specific while CAST is ANSI-standard.  I believe CONVERT gives you more options.  You can see other pros/cons here (http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/The-difference-between-CONVERT-and-CAST-in-SQL-Server)

Direct quotes from link...

> Because SQL Server provides both functions , there may be some confusion about which is best to use and under what circumstances.
>
> CONVERT is specific to SQL Server, and allows for a greater breadth of flexibility when converting between date and time values, fractional numbers, and monetary signifiers.
>
> CAST is the more ANSI-standard of the two functions, meaning that while it's more portable (i.e., a function that uses CAST can be used in other database applications more or less as-is), it's also less powerful.

Comment: Since the inputs are not datetime variables/columns but varchar strings, I'd use `CONVERT()` to make sure that the style 20 is used. `CAST(string AS DATE)` may depend on various locale/language connection/database/instance settings.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ and Scott: yes, `CAST` is dependent on the `LANGUAGE` session property. I just added a section (below the line) to [my answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148005/30859) illustrating this.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this silly comparison. Edited, there was a typo that @srutzky brought up. The results are close.

```
    ;with t as (
               select convert(date, GETDATE(),20) as fecha , 0 as num
             union all
             select convert(date, GETDATE()+num,20) as fecha, num+1 from t where num<1000000)
    select max(fecha)
      from t
    option (maxrecursion  0);

-- VS    
    ;with t as (
               select cast(GETDATE() as date) as fecha , 0 as num
             union all
             select cast(GETDATE()+num as date) as fecha, num+1 from t where num<1000000)
    select max(fecha)
      from t
    option (maxrecursion  0);
```

Results where very consistent:

- Convert: 8.6 seconds
- Cast: 8.7 seconds

Comment: You are converting datetime values, not varchar (as the question).

Comment: What I meant is I am converting a string into a date datatype (sorry!)

Comment: Thanks for the comparison vercelli. That was quite handy!

Comment: @pmdci you are welcome. Converting varchar as ypercube said gave me closer results (0.1 seconds of difference)

Comment: @pmdci also keep in mind what ypercube said about language dependance of CAST()

Comment: @ypercube - I was intrigued by your example and wanted to play a little more.  I used your original example as did see where CAST seemed to be the clear winner.  I then modified your example to GetDate() once into a variable and then used that across your example.  My results were not as consistent and in a few cases, CONVERT came in faster - I'm trying to figure out why that would be the case.

Comment: @ScottHodgin `CAST` and `CONVERT` are the same operation internally (CAST is just an alias for CONVERT with a style of "0"). This can be seen clearly in the XML execution plan. The test contained in this answer is flawed as it is using `GETDATE()+num` for the CONVERT test but only `GETDATE()` for the CAST test, and those are very different things. Please see my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148005/30859) for details.

Comment: @srutzky You are right. Already edited and repeated the test.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ and vercelli: it shouldn't matter in the end what is being converted to what as CAST is just an alias for CONVERT with a "style" of "0". The test here shows a difference only because it is not comparing the same thing in both cases. In the CONVERT test it uses an expression that needs to be evaluated per row, while the CAST test uses an expression that can be evaluated once as the plan is being compiled and stored as a constant. ( -1 )

Comment: Removed the -1 now that the example code has been edited to be the same between the two tests. Thanks for fixing that. I wasn't trying to be overly critical / mean, either in my comments here or in my answer. I was just concerned that people would walk away with incorrect info.

Comment: @srutzky You weren't over critical! I really appreciate it. (+1)

Comment: @vercelli Glad it wasn't taken the wrong way. Written messages often come across as being snide / caustic, so I was wanting to clarify that I wasn't being negative about you :).